# CURL API to pass parameters in Bash script

Tags: python, linux, curl, icinga

Curl command to pass arguments in the ICINGA API:

I have a curl command and passing it on a Bash script, I need to have two variables in the POST method for this URL, How do i pass the parameter to the CURL command

```
curl -k -s -u 'root:icinga' -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X POST 'https://sample.com:5665/v1/actions/acknowledge-problem?type=Service' \
  -d '{ "author": "icingaadmin", "comment": " Working on it.", "notify": true, "filter": "host.name == {\"$1\} && service.name == {\"$2\}"" }''' \
  | python -m json.tool
```

The $1 and $2 should have hostname and servicenames respectively

Please help

thanks
Aravind

Answer (score 1):

If you use single quotes (`'like this'`) in bash, you get a literal string with no variable expansion.  That is, compare:

```
$ echo '$DISPLAY'
$DISPLAY
```

With:

```
$ echo "$DISPLAY"
:0
```

This is exactly the same situation as in your `curl` command line, where you have:

```
'{ "author": "icingaadmin", "comment": " Working on it.", "notify": true, "filter": "host.name == {\"$1\} && service.name == {\"$2\}"" }'''
```

There's actuall a number of quoting problems there starting with the `'''` at the end, and including the `""` just before the final `}`.  If you want those variables to expand you will need to move them outside of your single quotes.  You can do this:

```
'"host.name == {"'"$1"'"} && ...'
```

In this case, the `"$1"` is *outside* of the single quotation marks.  Alternatively, you can do this:

```
"\"host.name == {\"$1\"} ** ..."
```

Here we're just using double quotes on the outside, so variable expansion works normally, but we have to escape every literal `"` inside the string.

Using the first option, the final argument to `-d` would look like something like this ("something" because I'm not familiar with icinga):

```
'{ "author": "icingaadmin", "comment": " Working on it.", "notify": true, "filter": "host.name == {"'"$1"'"} && service.name == {"'"$2"'"}}'
```

If `$1` is `foo` and `$2` is `bar`, this gives you:

```
{ "author": "icingaadmin", "comment": " Working on it.", "notify": true, "filter": "host.name == {"foo"} && service.name == {"bar"}}
```

Comment: I was unable to execute with the same,Looks like the escape sequence is still not working.

Comment: In what way did it fail?